# HTML5 Not Loading Android 3.0 And Up?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have the following code load HTML5 into a webview but it does not seem to work past android 3.0 and not on ICS either. I was hoping to get some help on what may be causing the problem?

```
public class DodgerAsActivity extends Activity {
WebView webview;
AdView adView;

private class WebcadeViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebcadeViewClient());
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have this configuration setup and it works on most of the sites I have tried, including HTML5, javascript, flash, geolocations and more.

```
// Custom Chrome/WebView Clients
myWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient(); 
webView.setWebChromeClient(myWebChromeClient );
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();

// JavaScript Features
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);

// Various plug-ins
webViewSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
webViewSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

// Viewing preferences
webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webViewSettings.setNeedInitialFocus(false);
webViewSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webViewSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
webViewSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

// Cache
webViewSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

// Geolocations
webViewSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/your.app.name/geo");
```

Also, try deleting `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` what you're doing in it doesn't seem right...

Comment: I tried using those settings and the HTML5 still does not load up. Is there something I am missing? Something specific for higher versions of android?

Comment: There shouldn't be, what site are you trying to load ?

Comment: I am loading a local html5 file from the assets folder. I load it using the following: webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

Comment: For the sake of the test try loading http://html5.grooveshark.com, if it works, please post some of your HTML code, maybe the issue is not in the webView.